# SQL Update statement, need help to pass the value to the subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update, subquery

This is my SQL statement. It is not working.

```
UPDATE dbo.Smoothie
SET TotalCalories = (SELECT 
                        SUM(CASE WHEN (Unit = 2) THEN f.Energ_Kcal * f.GmWt_2 * si.Quantity / 100 
                                 ELSE f.Energ_Kcal * f.GmWt_1 * si.Quantity / 100 
                            END) AS calories
                     FROM dbo.SmoothieIngredients AS si
                     INNER JOIN dbo.FoodAbbrev AS f ON si.FoodId = f.Id
                     WHERE si.SmoothieId = SmoothieId  ---> i want to pass the SmoothieId from the main update statement to the subquery.
                    )
```

I tried to give it a name S2, still not working.

```
UPDATE dbo.Smoothie as S2
SET S2.TotalCalories = (SELECT 
                           SUM(CASE WHEN (Unit = 2) THEN f.Energ_Kcal * f.GmWt_2 * si.Quantity / 100 
                                    ELSE f.Energ_Kcal * f.GmWt_1 * si.Quantity / 100 
                                END) AS calories
                        FROM dbo.SmoothieIngredients AS si
                        INNER JOIN dbo.FoodAbbrev AS f ON si.FoodId = f.Id
                        WHERE si.SmoothieId = S2.SmoothieId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your query to create a new table and then set the value of TotalCalories to the value in the column.

So in this case :

```
UPDATE  dbo.Smoothie
SET     TotalCalories = s2.calories
FROM 
    ( SELECT    
         smoothieId,
         SUM(CASE WHEN (Unit = 2) THEN f.Energ_Kcal * f.GmWt_2 * si.Quantity / 100 
                                            ELSE f.Energ_Kcal * f.GmWt_1 * si.Quantity / 100 END) AS calories
         FROM      dbo.SmoothieIngredients AS si
         INNER JOIN dbo.FoodAbbrev AS f ON si.FoodId = f.Id
         GROUP BY SmoothieId
    ) AS s2
WHERE dbo.Smoothie.Id = s2.smoothieId
```

I may have the query slightly wrong but note the Group By in the query for the s2 table and then link the rows with the Where clause as normal.